# succeed + gerund or infinitive

Tags: gerunds, infinitives

The below question was asked in national English exam in Turkey:

Choose the best word or expression to fill the spaces in the passage.

> As Henry Hill, the actor Ray Liotta gives a complex portrayal of an Irish-Italian kid who succeeds in his youthful ambition ....... popularity as a wealthy gangster, only to have his position slowly eroded until it almost destroys him.

A) to gain B)gaining C) to have gained D)having gained E) to be gaining

My choice was b (gaining). But the correct answer is A (to gain). I thought  the phrase "succeed in " takes gerund not infinitive. Why am I wrong for the answer.

Comment: No: nouns do not license gerund-participial (_-ing_) clauses as complement, but they do license infinitivals, which explains why A. is correct.  Btw, "succeed in" is not a phrase, not a constituent, but verb+head of a following PP.

Comment: You want *succeeds in* to take a "gerund not infinitive." But you have skipped over the object *his youthful ambition.*

Comment: *Gaining* would be fine if there was a comma after *ambition* but there ain't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *... an Irish-Italian kid who succeeds in his youthful ambition .......*
> *popularity as a wealthy gangster, only to have his position slowly*
> *eroded until it almost destroys him.*

"Ambition" is a noun, but nouns do not license gerund-participial (-*ing*) clauses as complement, though they do license infinitivals, which explains why A. but not B. is correct.

Note that "succeed in" is not a phrase, not a single constituent, but part of two constituents: verb + head of a following PP.